# abs(x)cos(x) in Fourier space

Tags: fourier-analysis, euclidean-geometry, transformation

I am working on some problems concerning Fourier Transform and I am facing something I don't understand.

I am trying to understand what is the representation of the function f(x)=abs(x)cos(x) in the Fourier space.

In wolfram alpha (sorry for this ad.), I type:
Fourier(abs(x)*cos(x))

which gives me as result:
g(w)= -((Sqrt[2/Pi] (1 + ω^2))/(-1 + ω^2)^2)

Where w is the frequency variable.

- My first question is: what is a 'frequency variable'?

Now, If I understand well, I believe that Fourier(abs(x)*cos(x)) gives the projection of the function f(x)=abs(x)*cos(x) into the Fourier space.

So, to check this, if I put some sampled values of a range of the function f(x)=abs(x)*cos(x),
let's say: D={abs(0)*cos(0), abs(0.1)*cos(0.1), ......, abs(0.9)*cos(0.9)}
Then, by applying the Discrete Fourier Transform on such data D, I should get an approximation on values of g(w) for w in D.

Meaning that:
g(abs(0.5)*cos(0.5)) should be equal to DFT(D) at rank 6.

But, in Wolfram Alpha, when I compute the DFT of D:
Fourier{0*cos(0),0.1*cos(0.1),0.2*cos(0.2),0.3*cos(0.3),0.4*cos(0.4),0.5*cos(0.5),0.6*cos(0.6),0.7*cos(0.7), 0.8*cos(0.8),0.9*cos(0.9)}

I get, at rank 6:
-0.0957306 + 0. I

But g(0.5)=-((Sqrt[2/Pi] (1 + (0.5)^2))/(-1 + (0.5)^2)^2)=-1.77

I don't understand why wolfram alpha gives me this resultat for Fourier(f(x)).
I am lost...

- Can anybody tells me where am I wrong in my thoughts?
  Many thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The frequency variable is the argument of the Fourier transform $\omega $.
Your Fourier transform is a tricky one, the original function being not
absolutely or square integrable.  But it can be defined as a limit, see
below. We start with

\begin{eqnarray*}
f(a) &=&\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi }}\int_{-\infty }^{+\infty }dx\exp [i\omega
x]\exp [-a|x|]\cos x \\
&=&\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi }}\int_{-\infty }^{+\infty }dx\cos \omega x\exp
[-a|x|]\cos x=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi }}\int_{0}^{+\infty }dx\exp [-ax]\cos
\omega x\cos x \\
&=&\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi }}\int_{0}^{+\infty }dx\exp [-ax]\frac{1}{2}\{\cos
(\omega +1)x+\cos (\omega -1)x\}=\func{Re}\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi }}\frac{1}{2}%
\int_{0}^{+\infty }dx\exp [-ax]\{\exp [i(\omega +1)x]+\exp [i(\omega -1)x]\}
\\
&=&\func{Re}\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi }}\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{+\infty }dx\{\exp
[\{i(\omega +1)-a\}x]+[\{i(\omega -1)-a\}x]\} \\
&=&-\func{Re}\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi }}\frac{1}{2}\{\frac{1}{i(\omega +1)-a}+%
\frac{1}{i(\omega -1)-a}\}
\end{eqnarray*}
Then

\begin{eqnarray*}
&&\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi }}\int_{-\infty }^{+\infty }dx\exp [i\omega x]|x|\cos x
\\
&=&-\partial _{a}f(a)|_{a=0}=\func{Re}\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi }}\frac{1}{2}%
\partial _{a}\{\frac{1}{i(\omega +1)-a}+\frac{1}{i(\omega -1)-a}\}_{a=0} \\
&=&-\func{Re}\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi }}\frac{1}{2}\{\frac{1}{[i(\omega +1)-a]^{2}}%
+\frac{1}{[i(\omega -1)-a]^{2}}\}_{a=0} \\
&=&-\func{Re}\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi }}\frac{1}{2}\{\frac{1}{[i(\omega +1)]^{2}}+%
\frac{1}{[i(\omega -1)]^{2}}\}=\func{Re}\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi }}\frac{1}{2}\{%
\frac{1}{(\omega +1)^{2}}+\frac{1}{(\omega -1)^{2}}\} \\
&=&\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi }}\frac{1}{2}\frac{(\omega -1)^{2}+(\omega +1)^{2}}{%
(\omega +1)^{2}(\omega -1)^{2}}=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi }}\frac{1}{2}\frac{%
2\omega ^{2}+2}{(\omega ^{2}-1)^{2}}=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi }}\frac{\omega ^{2}+1%
}{(\omega ^{2}-1)^{2}}
\end{eqnarray*}
\funcRe denotes the real part of what follows (my LaTeX seems not to be compatible). My result is off by a -sign as compared to Wolfram but I leave that to you.

Comment: It looks like you want \func to get you the operator font.  You can do this with \operatorname{Re} to get $\operatorname{Re}$

Comment: Ok, understood, but I don't see the relation with g(w) and the DFT of a sampled signal of f(x). Isn't it strange to have an imaginary part when computing Fourier{0*cos(0),0.1*cos(0.1),0.2*cos(0.2),0.3*cos(0.3),0.4*cos(0.4),0.5*cos(0.5),0.6*cos(0.6),0.7*cos(0.7), 0.8*cos(0.8),0.9*cos(0.9)} and not in g(w) ?

Comment: Yes, one would not expect an imaginary part. Since the integrand is an even function of x the imaginary part of exp[iωx] does not contribute since it is odd in x and hence gives a vanishing contribution.